# To "take something under advisement"

Tags: idioms

Does the idiom "I'll take that under advisement" in a non-legal context always (or usually) mean "I'll ignore your advice"? i.e. is it a polite (or not-so-polite) way to snub someone?
For example, the following quote I [found on IBDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/quotes?item=qt0466636), which is from the movie [Die Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Hard) (emphasis added):

> **Hans Gruber:** [after bad guys hit police ram with rocket]
>   [in radio to bad guys]
>   **Hans Gruber:** Hit it, again.
>   **John McClane:** [in radio to Hans] Hans you motherfucker, you made your point! Let them pull back!
>   **Hans Gruber:** [in radio to McClaine] Thank you, Mr. Cowboy, **I'll take it under advisement.**
>   [to bad guys]
>   **Hans Gruber:** *Hit it, again.*

Comment: In theory it means that you will carefully consider the suggestion.  In practice, most of the time (except, perhaps, in formal communications) it means you will think about it for 30 seconds and then forget it.

Comment: Translation: I'd already made up my mind, but I was hoping I could get you on record suggesting the same thing so I could blame you if it all goes pear shaped.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on context and you are talking to, but it may well suggest that you are far from considering the issue in question:

Take something under [advisement](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+under+advisement): (TFD)

> - to hear an idea and think about it carefully. It's a good idea, but I'll have to take it under advisement. The suggestion was taken under advisement, and a reply was not expected for at least a month

Take under [advisement](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=take%20under%20advisement&defid=7826113) (Urban Dictionary)

> - The proper response to someone who request or advises you to do something you have no intention of doing.

Comment: I agree, but this is my question: how to tell which meaning is intended? My feeling is that the usual intention is the second: I've listened to your advice and I'm going to ignore it.

Comment: I'd say that is  also used like that. But the meaning intended  really  depends on  context and  also on the intonation used, sort of reading betweet the lines.

Answer (score 4):

It literally means "to take away, consider and get advice on". When used literally it essentially means "to consider deeply". But as with most English idioms it can be used ironically, for emphasis - and is often used so. Thus the meaning asked about of "to ignore the advice" is simply the ironic use of the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It literally functions the same as saying,

> I'll take that under consideration.

So far as I know, there is little difference in the connotation, either. My experience would suggest, "I've thought about it already and chosen a route. What you're saying might make sense, but it'll probably be more trouble than I'm willing to commit to really compare your suggestion with the route already chosen."

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful phrase in response to a suggestion (good or bad) or information (good or bad, relevent or irrelevent.)  The point is that hear what's being said and are not taking a position on it at this time.  The speaker might or might not have a position already but they are not committing to it. It's also a way to accept input while reminding someone that they aren't your supervisor.

When used informally it can be humorous or ironic, as has been pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

In the culture I grew up in it always firstly meant that something would be carefully considered. Anyone who thinks it is a gentle snub in any culture could find themselves completely out of step in the interaction.